# How can I watch for API data updates in react native such as new message received in a messaging app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to build a messaging app with react native and I don't want to use pre-built messaging components such as [gifted-chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) because what I want is to learn how to code such mechanisms.

Posting data is simple. I can just call my RESTful API whenever the "Send" button is pressed.

But then I would like messages sent by the other person to appear at the bottom of the conversation so that it looks like real time messaging. But how can I listen for new messages sent by the other person? Asking the API every 'n' seconds doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: You could use Sockets. There's a Node.js example that can get you started with emitting and listening for events [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat). These concepts can be translated to React Native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan suggested use sockets, there are plenty of tutorials that can show you how to implement real-time messaging in node.js with socketio. [Here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) is my favorite! A quick google search returns plenty more of varying degrees of simplicity.

Comment: Thanks Brayden and Dan, I'll have a look into socket.io!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build your own backend then you can try [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). You will find some tutorials on google about how to implement a chat app.